# Dealing with Exception in Overridden Interface in Java

Tags: java, generics, exception

I have a Java interface that I am implementing (EdgeProvider from JGraphT) and which is not allowed to be `null`. However, I'm instantiating a generic type in an overridden method and can't figure out how to deal with either `InstantiationException` or `IllegalAccessException` in a way that I can detect and cleanly break out of the execution flow.

```
EdgeProvider<V, E> ep = new EdgeProvider<V, E>() {
      @Override
      public E buildEdge(V from, V to, String label, Map<String, String> attributes) {
        try {
          return eClass.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
          return null;
        }
      }
    };
```

If I rethrow I just get a warning that I have unhandled exceptions. Any suggestions?

Comment: So let's start by asking exactly what you want to do should either of these exceptions occur.  Do you expect that an upstream caller should deal with it?  Or are you prepared to allow it to crash?

Comment: There is a convenient way to instantiate a class without exceptions, using a constructor reference. How are you getting `eClass`?

Comment: I'm happy to deal with it elsewhere, but if I can get an instance without exceptions even better. `eClass` is passed in as a parameter.

Comment: I've previously written a documentation example about it: https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/92/generics/10445 As long as you supply the class yourself like `SomeType.class` you should be able to replace that with a constructor reference.

Comment: @Jorn-Vernee thanks for the reference. I like that solution. I don't relly want to throw a `RuntimeException`, so I'd love to accept your comment as the answer.

Comment: @amb85 I've posted it as an answer, I wasn't sure before if you were using a class literal or not (I guess I should have asked that instead).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a way to instantiate a class without exceptions, using a constructor reference. For instance:

```
Supplier<SomeType> eCons = SomeType::new;
```

[`Supplier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Supplier.html) is used for a default constructor, but you can use any functional interface type (for instance one of the ones listed here: [Link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html)) that matches the signature of the constructor you want to reference (for instance one that takes arguments).

In the case of `Supplier`, you can call `get()`, to create a new instance:

```
EdgeProvider<V, E> ep = new EdgeProvider<V, E>() {
    @Override
    public E buildEdge(V from, V to, String label, Map<String, String> attributes) {
        return eCons.get();
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can throw a `RuntimeException` as only checked exception cannot be added to the declaration of an overrided method.

You could define a custom exception (subclass of `RuntimeException`) : `MyBuildEdgeException` that wraps the caught exception.

```
public class MyBuildEdgeException extends RuntimeException{
   public MyBuildEdgeException(Exception cause){
       super(cause);
   }
}
```

And now you could throw the exception in this way :

```
EdgeProvider<V, E> ep = new EdgeProvider<V, E>() {
      @Override
      public E buildEdge(V from, V to, String label, Map<String, String> attributes) throws MyBuildEdgeException{
        try {
          return eClass.newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
           throw new MyBuildEdgeException(e);      
        }
      }
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you specifically want them to be Exceptions, e.g. because they could be configuration issues or such, I consider them to be build/installations errors.

So I usually just turn around and re-throw them as `Error`, same as what would have happened if you called constructor/method directly, rather than using reflection:

```
try {
    // code
} catch (InstantiationException e) {
    throw new InstantiationError(e.getMessage());
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    throw new IllegalAccessError(e.getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add throws clause in the buildEdge method and there is no need to have the try/catch if you are not handling it like returning null and handle the exception in caller method.

Comment: They are checked exceptions, so I either need to deal with them or declare the method signature as throwing them. Since I can't change the method signature and still provide a valid override, I have to deal with them. Or as @davidxxx said, if I continue to use `eClass.newInstance()` and I don't want to hndle them myself, throw a `RuntimeException`, which is unchecked.

Comment: Sounds good to throw the RuntimeException and handle it in the caller.